# tokenize a string keeping delimiters in Python

Tags: python, string, split, tokenize

Is there any equivalent to `str.split` in Python that also returns the delimiters?

I need to preserve the whitespace layout for my output after processing some of the tokens.

Example:

```
>>> s="\tthis is an  example"
>>> print s.split()
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example']

>>> print what_I_want(s)
['\t', 'this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'an', '  ', 'example']
```

Thanks!

Comment: +1 - Interesting question, `splitlines` seems to have a `keepends` parameter, but no such thing for `split`. Seems odd (http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about

```
import re
splitter = re.compile(r'(\s+|\S+)')
splitter.findall(s)
```

Comment: elegant and easily expandable (think `(\s+|\w+|\S+)`).

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> re.compile(r'(\s+)').split("\tthis is an  example")
['', '\t', 'this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'an', '  ', 'example']
```

Answer (score 4):

the `re` module provides this functionality:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(\W+)', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', ', ', 'words', ', ', 'words', '.', '']
```

(quoted from the Python documentation).

For your example (split on whitespace), use `re.split('(\s+)', '\tThis is an example')`.

The key is to enclose the regex on which to split in capturing parentheses. That way, the delimiters are added to the list of results.

Edit: As pointed out, any preceding/trailing delimiters will of course also be added to the list. To avoid that you can use the `.strip()` method on your input string first.

Comment: not using the OP's string masks the fact that the empty string is included as the first element of the returned list.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post accordingly (although in this case, the OP's spec ("want to preserve whitespace") and his example were contradictory).

Comment: No, it wasn't... there was one example of the current behaviour, and another of the desired one.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at pyparsing?  Example borrowed from [the pyparsing wiki](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/greeting.py):

```
>>> from pyparsing import Word, alphas
>>> greet = Word(alphas) + "," + Word(alphas) + "!"
>>> hello1 = 'Hello, World!'
>>> hello2 = 'Greetings, Earthlings!'
>>> for hello in hello1, hello2:
...     print (u'%s \u2192 %r' % (hello, greet.parseString(hello))).encode('utf-8')
... 
Hello, World! → (['Hello', ',', 'World', '!'], {})
Greetings, Earthlings! → (['Greetings', ',', 'Earthlings', '!'], {})
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for pointing for the `re` module, I'm still trying to decide between that and using my own function that returns a sequence...

```
def split_keep_delimiters(s, delims="\t\n\r "):
    delim_group = s[0] in delims
    start = 0
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if delim_group != (char in delims):
            delim_group ^= True
            yield s[start:index]
            start = index
    yield s[start:index+1]
```

If I had time I'd benchmark them xD

Comment: no need regex or creating your own wheels if you have python 2.5 onwards.. see my answer.